# How can I hide "Groups" and cancel button in CNContactPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cancel-button, contactpicker

Im using a CNContactPickerViewController  and I want to hide the cancel and the group buttons
I tried   `contactPickerViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil` and

```
contactPickerViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

but that doesnt work.. 
Here my code to create the controller

```
let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()

    contactPickerViewController.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 0",
        argumentArray: nil)

    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
    contactPickerViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    contactPickerViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    presentViewController(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Help anyone? Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to remove the cancel button?  Users hate being trapped in non-dismissable dialogs.  Why would you want to hide the Group button?  If the user has made groups so they can find their contacts easily, why would you want to take that away from them?

Comment: I do need the cancel button but I want it as the left bar button and three buttons make the UI overload but thanks for answering

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @ManiaChamp no  , I write my own contactPickerView , the new Contact framework made it very simple ... Good luck

Comment: @jerem will u share your code for reference. I am also stuck at same. I want to show only cancel button